# How to get a percentile for an empirical data distribution and get it's x-coordinate?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy, percentile

I have some discrete data values, that taken together form some sort of distribution.
This is one of them, but they are different with the peak being in all possible locations, from 0 to end.
[image]

So, I want to use it's quantiles (percentiles) in Python. I think I could write some sort of function, that would some up all values starting from zero, until it reaches desired percent. But probably there is a better solution? For example, to create an empirical distribution of some sort in SciPy and then use SciPy's methods of calculating percentiles?

In the very end I need x-coordinates of a left percentile and a right percentile. One could use 20% and 80% percentiles as an example, I will have to find the best numbers for my case later.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**
some example code for almost what I want.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
distribution = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
left, right = np.percentile(distribution, [20, 80])
print left, right
```

This returns percentiles themselves, I need to get their x-coordinates somehow. For normal distribution here it is possible, obviously, but I have a distribution of an unknown shape, so if a percentile isn't equal to one of the values (which is the most common thing, obviously), it becomes much more complicated.

Comment: Please provide sample data (better with inline code, for example you can use random.seed and [random sampling](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html)) and expected results.

Comment: You are not guaranteed that the percentile actually is in your array. It may be an average of two elements. What index would you want then?

Comment: That is a good question. Probably, the best solution would be to use linear interpolation between to closest data points.

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for empirical CDF then you may use statsmodels [ECDF](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tools.tools.ECDF.html). For percentiles/quantiles you can use numpy [percentile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html)

Comment: IMHO, this is better suited as comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had a look at your links - is it possible to use numpy.percentile with ECDF?

Comment: @Ilya what exactly are you trying to calculate? from your question `percentile` seems to be the answer, but if it is not what exacctly are you looking for?

Comment: Percentile could be very useful here, but I don't know how to use it with empirical distribution. And how to get x-coordinate of a percentile.

Answer (score 0):

OK, for now I have written the following function and now use it:

```
def percentile(distribution, percent):
    percent = 1.0*percent/100
    cum_percent = 0
    i=0
    while cum_percent <= percent:        
        cum_percent = cum_percent + distribution[i]
        i = i+1
    return i
```

It is a little rough, because returns an index of the most close value to the left of the required value. For my purposes it works as a temporary solution, but I would love to see a working solution for precise percentile x-coordinate determination.

Comment: what is data here? it's still unclear what do you want

Comment: Um. distribution is an np.array holding the values for a distribution shown in the question. percent is a number in [0-100], corresponding to percentile I want.

Comment: let me repeat, what is **data**? ;) i.e. what you sum up

Comment: Oh, right, sorry, I changed the naming at some point and didn't do it properly =) there is no **data** =) Will edit the answer.

Comment: then next questions: 1) you sum distribution, that is integrate. did you normalize it previously? in your example  `distribution.sum()` yields -45.256707490195311`

Comment: 2) distribution is not sorted (at least in your example), this also drastically affects your function results

Comment: Yeah, sure, in real life it is normalized, meaning all elements were divided by it's sum

Comment: Do you mean my random-sampling example, or my plot example?

Comment: random for sure, I can't reproduce your plot, so don't treat it as a part of your question

Comment: OK, it is not sorted, but why does it matter? I don't want to study normal distribution, the shape of it doesn't matter :)